# Juju not deploying zookeeper when deploying on OpenStack

Tags: juju, openstack

I am using juju with openstack, when it bootstraps, it dose not deploy zookeeper on the bootstrap VM. I logged into this VM to verify.

1) How is zookeeper and other software installed on juju VM, is it ssh and apt-get during bootstrap process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you bootstrap, the zookeeper machine is not supposed to exist already, but you should be able to boot new  vm with nova.

Here is how it looks like here:

```
melmoth@x220:~$ nova list
+----+------+--------+----------+
| ID | Name | Status | Networks |
+----+------+--------+----------+
+----+------+--------+----------+
melmoth@x220:~$ juju bootstrap
2013-06-20 14:00:44,252 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'kikoo' (origin: ppa type: openstack)...
2013-06-20 14:00:58,079 INFO 'bootstrap' command finished successfully
melmoth@x220:~$ nova list
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+----------+
|                  ID                  |          Name         | Status | Networks |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+----------+
| 705b97fa-6579-43e2-af3a-f504b74b7ee2 | juju kikoo instance 0 | BUILD  |          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+----------+
```

The new "juju kikoo instance 0" machine is the one where zookeeper will be installed.

I can see how the boot process is going with:

```
nova console-log 705b97fa-6579-43e2-af3a-f504b74b7ee2
```

You may want to run "juju --verbose bootstrap" in order to learn more about why is there no new vm launched.

Here is my environments.yaml file:

```
environments:
    kikoo:
      type: openstack
      control-bucket: pierre-bucket
      admin-secret:  asecretphrase 
      default-series: precise
      #be sure you can boot machine using nova boot with this image:
      default-image-id: f2ca48ce-30d5-4f1f-9075-12e64510368d
      juju-origin: ppa
```

See https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-openstack.html for details.